# Fejer-Riesz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I'm trying to apply the Fejer-Riesz Lemma constructively. The lemma says that for a Laurent polynomial $a(z) = \sum_{-n}^na_jz^j$ with $a_j = \bar a_{-j}$ and $a(e^{i\theta})\geq0$ on the complex unit circle, there exists a polynomial $b(z) = \sum_{0}^nb_jz^j$ such that $a(e^{i\theta})=|b(e^{i\theta})|^2$ for all $\theta$.

The [proof](http://people.virginia.edu/~jlr5m/Papers/FejerRiesz.pdf) is rather simple (in hindsight).

My particular scenario is a simpler version, where $a_j=a_{-j}\in\mathbb R$, which gives an even stronger result: $a(z) = b(z)b(1/z)$ for *all* complex $z$. But I'm not managing to use this constructively - I'm not sure in general there is a constructive approach, because we can't explicitly reduce all polynomials. In any case, my particular case is,

$$a(z) = (4-128\theta) + (112\theta-1)(z+z^{-1}) + 64\theta(z^2+z^{-2}) + 16\theta(z^3+z^{-3})$$

I'm simply not managing to find $\{b_j\}$. This of course reduces to a system of nonlinear equations, if we simply compare coefficients, but that wasn't particularly fruitful either. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The parameter $\theta$ is a constant on a smallish neighbourhood of zero. It shouldn't be important for the general result, although if it helps, you can assume $\theta\in[-\frac 1{10},\frac 1 {10}]$.

Comment: Why is there some $\theta$ in your expression of $a(z)$ in the last line?

Comment: I'm interested in a family of $a(z)$ dependent on a parameter. It's not too difficult to show that there exists some neighbourhood of zero for which all $a_\theta(z)$ are indeed non-negative on the complex unit circle. Although I didn't mention this so as not to bog down the problem.

Comment: It's still important to know what this thing is. Perhaps you should write $a_{\theta}(z)$ just that you don't write things that confuse us more than enlighten us. Interesting question, +1.

Comment: If it simplifies things, consider it a constant in $[-\frac 1{10},\frac 1{10}]$

Comment: The proof is actually quite constructive, although for high degree (high seems to be $> 1$ here...) it seems practically speaking impossible to find this polynomial because you will have to solve for some roots of high degree polynomial (and when solving for roots, $> 4$ is too much).

Comment: That's what I meant when I wrote "we can't explicitly reduce all polynomials"

Comment: @davin did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @geometrikal, I did. The field is called spectral factorisation. For my purposes it sufficed to solve some polynomials numerically, although unless you need just a few examples this isn't the way to go, since accurate and appropriate numerical techniques abound. I suggest something like Tim N. T. Goodman, Charles A. Micchelli, and Sebastiano Seatzu. Spectral Factorization of Laurent Polynomials. Advances in Computational Mathematics, 7:429–454, 1997.

Comment: @davin Thanks for that reference. I'm having to solve a lot of small degree (< 21) real trig polynomials and halving the number of roots should give a good speed up.

Comment: @geometrikal, interesting. I don't know if the Fejer-Riesz lemma is applicable because (1) complex trig polynomials have a corresponding Laurent polynomial, but I don't see how real trig polynomials can be represented as Laurent polynomials. (2) Taking real and imaginary parts of the Laurent polynomial corresponding to a complex trig polynomial with real coefficients is a small step, but I don't see where this could lead, since you would have to satisfy the positivity condition, which is equivalent to the polynomial being nonnegative for the entire real line.

Comment: @davin Thanks for that information. The particular set of polynomials I have to find the roots for is defined the same as $a(z)$ in your question, and $a(e^{i\theta}) \geq 0$. They are the modulus of another trig polynomial. When I calculate the roots they always occur in conjugate pairs. Does that meet the criteria? The application is signal processing.

Comment: @geometrikal, I'm not 100% clear on your context. When you say real trig polynomial, do you mean what is written here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_polynomial or do you mean complex trig polynomial with real coefficients (the difference is the $i$)? Every polynomial with real coefficients admits its non-real roots in conjugate pairs, so that's trivial. If you say you have the positivity constraint and Laurent polynomial representation (I don't see how that is achieved) then you can indeed use this lemma.

Comment: @davin I mean something that can be written $\sum_{-n}^{n} a_j e^{i n \theta}$, i.e. $z = e^{i\theta}$, where $a_j = \hat{a}_{-j}$, $a_j$ can be complex, and $\sum_{-n}^{n} a_j e^{i n \theta}$ is positive and real (for $z$ on the unit circle?).

Comment: @davin Ahh I was confused. I'm trying to find the maxima of the polynomial with the above constraints via the roots of its *derivative*. Sorry. :) Thanks for the comments and help.

Comment: Are you trying something like in this paper Rioul, Duhamel (1993): [A Remez exchange algorithm for orthonormal wavelets...](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~rioul/publis/199302rioulduhamel.pdf)?